# Removing items from recycler view generates an error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to remove certain items from RecyclerView. I am able to remove a single item at a time but unable to remove multiple items at once. Below is the code for removing items:

```
final  Online2_G_S online2_g_s = online2_g_sList.get(position);

if (online2_g_s.getpMrp()==0){
   removeItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
}

private void removeItem(final int position) {
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try{
                Log.i("sand36", String.valueOf(position)+" "+online2_g_sList.get(position));
                online2_g_sList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, online2_g_sList.size());

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("sand36", String.valueOf(e));
            }
        }
});
```

and here is the error I am getting while removing items:

```
09-14 09:09:36.816 26394-26394/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sand36: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4   
09-14 09:09:36.817 26394-26394/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sand36: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
09-14 09:09:36.870 26394-26394/com.parse.AwaazDo I/sand36: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
```

Comment: from where are you getting the position in `online2_g_sList.get(position)` ?

Comment: fron onBindViewHolder(final OnlineAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code in this

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, online2_g_sList.size());
```

use this line above.

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, online2_g_sList.size());
online2_g_sList.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);`
```

Comment: will you please elaborate the difference?

Comment: when u try to delete item. before removing  item (notifyItemRangeChanged(position, online2_g_sList.size());) this line change range of your list size so that only available positions or size of  array list is inside your Array List.

Comment: thank you, I was eliminating data before attaching it to adapter, but This is the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to remove the item directly from within the adapter then its likely to give indexoutofbound exception.

What you have to do is create an interface which is implemented by the parent of recyclerview and pass it to the recycler adapter during creation, then when you for example listen for remove button in your recycler item, call the interface method with the item and then parent will remove the item and notify.

```
public interface OnRecyclerItemInteraction{
  public void onItemRemoveClicked(Online2_G_S  item);
}
```

In your parent implementation:

```
@override
public void onItemRemoveClicked(Online2_G_S  item){
  int index = yourList.indexOf(item);
  yourList.remove(item);
  yourAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
}
```

finally in your bindViewHolder:

```
closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
   @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemInteraction.onItemRemoveClicked(thisViewsItem)
            }
})
```